# Error: Doesn't contain a public definition of GetEnumerator

Tags: c#, html, enumerator

When I am trying to run the application I am getting this error constantly i.e

```
"CS1579: foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'Models.FloorPlanViewModel' because 'Models.FloorPlanViewModel' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'"
```

its crashing at foreach of SummaryTable.cshtml

```
Line 34:             </tr>
Line 35: 
Line 36:             @foreach (var item in Model)
Line 37:             {
Line 38:                 <tr>
```

Below is FloorPlanViewModel

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using USTGlobal.WorkBench.Repository;

namespace UI.Models
{
    public class FloorPlanViewModel
    {

        public IEnumerable<SummaryConfiguration> sumConfig { get; set; }



    }

}
```

Any help plz?

Comment: More details required to accurately answer the question.

Does the controller return List< FloorPlanViewModel> or just FloorPlanViewModel?

What are you trying to iterate over in the view?

Assuming FloorPlanViewModel is returned from the Controller action, Guilherme's answer would solve the issue.

Comment: @ChandraSekharV You are right, but I assumed that the controller returns `FloorPlanViewModel` because of the error: `'FloorPlanViewModel' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'`

Comment: thanks a lot. looks like error is gone :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@foreach (var item in Model.sumConfig)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add a more detailed explanation.

**When we can use a foreach?**
The foreach statement is used to iterate through an object collection that implements the System.Collections.IEnumerable or System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable interface.
[foreach, in (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/foreach-in)

**Why your code does not work?**

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
```

Your want iterate through *Model*, but **it does not implement IEnumerable.**

**Why the code of the accepted answer works?**

```
@foreach (var item in Model.sumConfig)
```

Because *Model.sumConfig* **is of type IEnumerable**.